# How to stretch selected vertices to mathfunction or bezier

Tags: mesh, modifiers, bezier-curves, vertices

**The situation:** 
I want to create a splint for my forearm by using a 3d scan.

My plan was to design the basic model with a grease pencil and bsurfaces and add the thickness with the solidify modifier.

**My problem:**
The entire outline is kind of random, if i use the grease pencil.
I tried to use the gstretch function (looptools addon), but logically I again create a random line.

[image]
[image]

To reproduce the whole process for another different armscan with a similar outline, I thought I can stretch the outer vertices to a predifined bezier, path, mathfunction, script? But unfortunately I didn't found a way yet.

Comment: Have you looked into the [Bsurfaces](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.64/Bsurfaces_1.5) addon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want can be done in a number of manners, but most of them are retopology tools:

RetopoMT by Blenderlounge:

https://youtu.be/op2rMKDEUzQ?t=566

SpeedRetopo by Cedric Lepiller

https://youtu.be/BFfqePn8nKI?t=21

https://youtu.be/NdbBX957JYo?t=286

Retopoflow by cgcookie:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9qidVmJjtBA

Bsurfaces:

https://youtu.be/3VC98kiy10Q?t=117

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mptQWDbKhW0

Mira Tools for editing loops as curves:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iO4OjsqJpxQ

Curve Tools for nurbs modeling:

https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?221213-Tools-for-curves

Also, on the same LoopTools addon that you use, there are options on the W menu for relaxing and spacing of the vertices, they may be useful in your case.

Comment: The 'Curve Stretch Tool' in 'Mira Tools' is exactly what i needed. Thanks!